# Fetch data from query params in angular 4 in routing

Tags: angular, routes

Hi I am new to angular 4 and I am creating a shop page where when a user clicks the jeans link it should visit the shop page with the filtered jeans products. (Please let me know if you need more info about the code, I can add it.)

In Home Component -

```
<a [routerLink]="['/shop']">Jeans</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/shop']">Shirts</a>
```

I have created a shop component and given route as `/shop`. In my shop component I have created the service which fetches the data from -

```
import { Products } from './products';

export const PRODUCTS: Products[] = [
{
    id: 1,
    productCat:'Jeans',
    product: [
        {
            prodId: 1a;
            productName: 'Trendy Jeans',
        },
    ],
},
{
    id: 2,
    productCat:'Shirts',
    product: [
        {
            prodId: 1b;
            productName: 'Trendy Shirts',
        },
    ],
}
]
```

So, is it possible to use `query params` or `optional params` in angular routing to fetch only jeans data in shop page after clcking the link jeans or shirts data after clicking the link shirts. If its not possible can you please suggest me a different method.

Comment: Yes you can send the data using `query params`. But you have to process the data(extract jeans data from the list and add to query params)

Comment: Hi @AnuradhaGunasekara thank you so much, can you please show me how? Do you need more info about the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, query params are available in angular. Your link might look something like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/shop']" [queryParams]="{type: 'jeans'}">Jeans</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/shop']" [queryParams]="{type: 'shirt'}">Shirts</a>
```

Accessing queryParams in your shop component would look something like this:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams
      .flatMap(queryParams => {
        if (queryParams.type === 'shirt') {
           // get shirt
        } else if(queryParams.type === 'jeans') {
           // get jeans
        }
      })
```

Comment: Hi ` if (queryParams.type === 'shirt') {` line its giving me an error of  - Argument of type '(queryParams: Params) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Params, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'. Am I missing something

Comment: I think you're getting this because `.flatMap` expects you return a function that returns an observable. I was assuming you would call a service that would return an observable list of shirts or jeans. If that's not the case then you should be able to replace `.flatMap` with `.subscribe`

Comment: Hi! Thanks or this @Crhistian Ramirez can you please help me get the filter for the following `[routerLink]="['/shop']" [queryParams]="{ type: 'jeans'}"` using subscribe. I am using a product service. For more info `productList: Products[];` and in `ngOnInit this.productList = this.productservice.getProducts();`

Answer (score 1):

In your routes file.

```
{ path: 'shop/:data, component: ShopComponent }
```

Then in your products componet where you have links to the shop component, Pass the parameters you want.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

your component code goes here. And for the link click function add this.

```
this.router.navigate(['/project-details',data]);
```

data in here is for your extracted data.

And in your product component constructor or ngOnInit sunscribe for the route params.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      const data: params.data;
    });
  }
```

Hope this helps. And if you need to find more about angular routing and navigation follow [this](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-definition-with-a-parameter) link.